Failed vsix (for RDLC) has caused visual studio to not launch
Setup: offline/isolated visual studio 2019 pro instance on windows server 2019.
previously, VS worked fine, and i needed to modify an RDLC report in VS.  i tried to install Microsoft.RdlcDesigner.vsix, and it froze at 'Verifying' for a very long time.  I closed the window and now Visual Studio refuses to launch.
At first, it claimed the installation was not complete, and i found the vsix install still running, so i closed it.  Now i get 'The setup for this installation of Visual Studio is not complete'.  Am i just screwed and have to reinstall VS in its entirety???
any help is appreciated

in the end, alas, a reinstall was required...:(.  and i still have no way to edit rdlc files.

Hi, did you any detailed error message in your VSIXInstaller_xxx.log file?

For this issue, i would suggest you try the following to troubleshoot:
1.What is the version of Microsoft RDLC Report Designer you download and install?
Microsoft RDLC Report Designer 2017-2019
Microsoft RDLC Report Designer 2022
2.Open your extension installation log(e.g:dd_VSIXInstaller_xxx.log) and check if there are detailed error messages. Folder path: usually located to "C:\Users\your user name\AppData\Local\Temp"
3.Navigate to Manage Extension menu in Visual Studio and check if you have installed this extension. If so, click uninstall to install it. If you cannot launch visual studio, you can navigate to "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE" and run the following command:
vsixinstaller /uninstall: your ExtensionID


Note: you can get ExtensionId from extension.vsixmanifest file.
 <Identity Id="B12781A3-35C8-446D-BD72-6051FCA1CBF9" Version="17.0.0" Language="en-US" Publisher="Microsoft" />
 <DisplayName>Microsoft RDLC Report Designer</DisplayName>

4.Reinstall the extension and wait it completed to see if you can install successfully.
